# xclip fails to set selection when using tramp

Tags: tramp, shell, clipboard, x11

I use Emacs in the terminal (`emacs -nw`) and [xclip.el](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/xclip.html) for synchronising the kill ring with the X clipboard. Under normal circumstances this works fine, but when visiting buffers with tramp xclip is not able to set the X clipboard. I believe something is failing with the xclip shell command when run through tramp, but I don't know how to debug it.

Investigating so far I have found:

- Yanking in a tramp buffer works fine and is able to yank from the kill ring or X clipboard.
- Killing text under tramp causes the text to be added to the kill ring, but the X clipboard does not get set.
- It doesn't matter which user or host is used to access files through tramp - I can visit files using `/sudo:myusername@localhost:/...` and the failure still occurs.
- xclip processes don't get closed after killing text in a tramp process, which is what leads me to believe something is failing there. I see the text below when I close Emacs. (This does not occur when killing to xclip in a normal buffer).

`Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway? (yes or no)`

```
Process [v]     Status  Buffer          TTY          Command                                   
xclip           run     --              /dev/pts/6   /bin/sh -i
xclip<1>        run     --              /dev/pts/7   /bin/sh -i
```

xclip.el uses `start-file-process` and `process-send-string` to run xclip, but I don't know how to debug these functions or see if there is any error output. There are no errors in the Messages buffer.

Is there something I can do to fix this problem or some way to debug what is going wrong with the xclip shell commands?

Comment: Could you try and replace `start-file-process` with `start-process` everywhere in `xclip.el` to see if it fixes it for you?  In any case I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: @Stefan, Yes, this appears to solve the issue. I have sent a bug report to the email list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to authors Stefan Monnier and Leo Liu this [bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33399) was fixed in [xclip.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/xclip.html) version 1.5.